# .Net & SQL Server 2005: preventing injection when querying against a list

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, .net-4.0

I have a search form that needs to query another system's SQL Server 2005 database (so I have no control over their stored procedures/functions).

Generally to prevent injection, my code would look something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id = @Id", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1234);
```

This scenario is a little different, in that they are requesting that the form allows for a comma separated list of values to work as well.  So how would I do something like this:

```
string ids = "1234, 1235, 1236";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id IN (" + ids + ")", conn);
```

In a secure way, with one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the best solution I could come up with; if anyone sees any vulnerabilities please let me know:

```
string idList = "1234, 1235, 1236";

XElement ids = new XElement("ds");
foreach (string s in idList.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(id => id.Trim()))
    ids.Add(new XElement("d", s));

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id IN (SELECT T.ids.value('.', 'int') FROM @Ids.nodes('/ds/d') AS T(ids))", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Ids", ids.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Xml });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways that you can pass a list in and do type checking inside SQL. If you use a stored procedure instead of this ad hoc SQL you can simply pass the list in as a string parameter and parse it inside the procedure. It will simply error out if the list has any non-integers.

For example this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitInts]
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item FROM ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int') FROM 
            ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
              + '</i>').query('.') ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)
          ) AS y WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
GO
```

Can be called like this:

```
SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitInts('1234, 1235, 1236', ',');
```

Results:

```
Item
----
1234
1235
1236
```

If you try to use any strings at all, it bombs:

```
SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitInts('1234; DROP TABLE bobbytables;', ',');
```

Result:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
> Conversion failed when converting
>   the nvarchar value '1234; DROP TABLE bobbytables;' to data type int.

So with that split function in place, your stored procedure could be written this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetMyTable
    @List VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT t.col1, t.col2 --, ...
      FROM dbo.myTable AS t
      INNER JOIN dbo.SplitInts(@List, ',') AS i
      ON t.Id = i.Item;
END
GO
```

And this could be called from .NET with a strongly-typed string parameter `@List` with no concerns about SQL injection whatsoever - as long as you pass the parameter into a proper call using a `StoredProcedure` commandType and don't try to build the `EXEC ...` string yourself.

In SQL Server 2008 you could go a step further and use Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs), which let you populate a *set* of data to a stored procedure parameter from, say, a DataTable.

Comment: Hi Aaron - from the post, one of my limitations is I have no control over their stored procedures or functions, otherwise I would do something similar to this

Comment: Well, hopefully someone else has something clever, since you can't just supply the parameter as a string - there are no arrays in SQL Server. Perhaps in .NET you could loop through the string and verify that they're all integers before putting them back together and building your query. Is the client interested in preventing injection? Maybe they would be more open to allowing you to create stored procedures to prevent it.

Comment: I think a simple combination of `String.Split` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) and `Int.TryParse` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) could do this in .NET.